# Need to create the reference of capabilities for mobile testing by selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I just started mobile automation using selenium and appium. I need to create a object which directly enter the value in textbox. Currently first it is launching the app then I am able to reach on the perticular textbox . I do not want to launch the app again and again I just want to enter the information in textbox,dropdown  etc.. Please help me to write the program...

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service, and it's also not a programming school.

Answer (score 0):

You can get textbox by id using uiautomatorviewer if it's android or by xpath  if it's on webbrowser, then you can use

`driver.findElement(By.id("id here as string of textbox")).sendKeys("what you want to send");`

at the end you can confirm by clicking accept or something using

`driver.findElement(By.id("id of accept button")).click();`

keep in mind that if you use id you must use By.id, xpath then By.xpath and so on.